# How to show a button only in first grouped row in AngularJS ui-grid 3.0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

For the grouped ui-grid in the Plunker link, the third column, how to let the button only shows in the groupHeader rows?

[image: ui-grid]

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KNNUPhAmD91HeHkDaQyr?p=preview

I tried using the following cellTemplate on the third column, but it doesn't work, since the third column is not a grouped column.

```
cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="!col.grouping || col.grouping.groupPriority === undefined || col.grouping.groupPriority === null || ( row.groupHeader && col.grouping.groupPriority === row.treeLevel )" class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>'
```

Most of the codes of the grid are from official UI Grid [tutorial 209](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping). I just added the button part.

Comment: can you update your plunker? There is currently no grid. And also your picture ( which you actually can upload here)

Comment: @Asqan Please check it again. I just updated it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a `ng-show` in your cell template

```
<button ng-show="row.treeLevel==0" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
```

Here is the working version of your Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/vYpAi4AV0a9cidcoejFY?p=preview

Comment: as soon as you ungroup, no buttons shows up anymore which i guess is not a correct behaviour the solution is to use ng-show="row.treeLevel == 0 || !row.treeLevel"